# Test Suite for Python selenium does not work

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I have created a test suite however only first test case runs and then execution stops. Second test cases (class) doesn't execute. I am writing these tests in Eclipse.

`TestSuite.py`

```
class Test_Suite(unittest.TestCase):   
    def test_main(self):         
        # suite of TestCases
        self.suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        self.suite.addTests([            
            #unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(WebdriverTest1.WebdriverTest1),
            unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestCases.Test_script),
            unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestCases.Test1_DisabledLoginButton),
            unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestCases.Test2_WrongUserName),
        ])
        runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
        runner.run (self.suite) 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
    #unittest.TextTestRunner().run(Test_Suite)
```

I created 3 classes which I want to execute one after another. First class is executed OK but remaining classes are not touched.

`TestCases.py`

```
class Test_script(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_clickphone(self):
        #script

class Test1_DisabledLoginButton(unittest.TestCase):        
    def Test1_DisabledLoginButton(self):
        #script

class Test2_WrongUserName(unittest.TestCase):
    def Test2_WrongUserName(self):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `unittest` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#basic-example), your test cases must start with the letters `test`.

Change your tests to `test1_DisabledLoginButton` and `test2_WrongUserName`; you had your Ts capitalized

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried, but still could not succeeded.

Comment: inding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 10.513s

OK
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 10.511s

OK